# Amazon aws user-data python script

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, boto

Think like I am inside a aws server(say X) and from this I am launching another instance(server)say Y, at the time of launching the server Y I have to pass some 'user-data' through the parameter of launching server Y. I want to pass X server pvt IP, and instance ID through user data to Y server. I wrote using python something like below.

```
user_data_script= '#!/bin/bash'+'\n'+'sudo su'+'\n'+'cd '+'\n'+'echo '+"dispatcher_id="+dispatch_id+' >'+'/etc/scripts/id.txt'+'\n'+'echo '+"dispatcher_ip="+dispatch_ip+' >>'+'/etc/scripts/id.txt'+'\n'+'/etc/scripts/publisherpy.sh'
```

The above `dipatcher_id`, ip I will get through metadata, since I am inside X server.

The above code should make something like this inside the Y server id.txt file:

```
 dipatcher_id='i-123567by7'
 dipatcher_ip='10.45.66.76'
```

Comment: I can't get what you are doing? you are trying to launch the string your are constructing on the fly from python as a bash script in a remote server, is this right?

Comment: from a remote server X i am launching another remote server Y and at the time of launching Y ,I am passing something called User-data as parameter to the Instance Y so that Once the Y SERVER in running condition It will contain a file of ID,IP of X server which we are passing through above User-data bash script(once the Y server gets launch this shell script gets triggered)..it is python based..I am very new to this world so this much only I understand...thanks for your reply

Comment: Code worked fine..tested.there were some syntax issue